# Recharge calculation for an aquifer

Tags: precipitation, evaporation

I want to calculate recharge for an aquifer for which I have calculated daily ET by Haude's method and I also have daily precipitation data. How can I calculate recharge per minutes.

Comment: I know I have to first calculate field capacity and wilting point. Most methods estimate wilting point and field capacity by percentage of sand, silt and clay content. What if more than 50% of soil is > 2mm i.e fall in 'gravel' range?

Answer (score 2):

This methodology won't work. Haude's method only gives a rough estimate of evaporation. Consider the hydrologic cycle: Rainfall = evaporation (or evapotranspiration) + runoff + surface detention + soil moisture storage + infiltration +/- interbasin transfer. It sounds like you don't have nearly enough data to estimate the aquifer recharge.

Comment: You are right that Haude is very crude but I don't have enough data. Also I don't need to have very exact recharge measurement. I value of recharge is to be added in groundwater to account for its affect to change water table. Water table in said model actually varies by other factors. I have data about radiation, temp, rain, humidity, wind speed.